# too much work for one thread(database performance)

Tags: android, database, multithreading

at the moment I develope an android app that receives data from bluetooth and store these data in a local database. Therefore I wrote a class called Datamanager which manages the local database (inserts, reads, deletes...).
First I checked the needed time for only save some local generated data. Storing 10000 objects takes 100ms. 
If I receive the data from bluetooth and store it, it takes 1700ms. But this is not fast enough because I receive 10000 objects per second.

I think it's because receive and store is too much work for one thread. I call my datamanager inside the thread which receives the data from bluetooth.

Now I am asking myself how could I speed up the storing while receiving data?

I tried to call the store function of my datamanager class in a asynctask, but this is more slow then without the asynctask.

How can I speedup the storing operation during receiving? Bounded Service for Storing? Can I use multi cores?

I am happy about some recommendation

Comment: What kind of data are you storing? Are you serializing it? Did you try using transactions? You should be a bit more specific to get helpful advice

Comment: I store own data. 15 bytes per object. With Couchbase you can't use transactions. I take a arraylist of 10000 objects and save this as attachement to a dokument.

Comment: But this is not my problem. Wirhout receiving data it is fast enough. Only if i receive data it is to slow. So my problem is to handle the process utilization. I receivve the data inside an intentservice. If I call the store method inside this it it not fast enough.